# Create a mapping hash in perl

Tags: perl

I have 2 string from which i want to create a hash , first_string value will be key and second script  will be value for key. Below are the 2 diffrent string data.

```
First   Second
PY       AB
CH       BC
QQ       CD
TD       EF
TD       IG
TD       IH
TD       RD
TD       GD
ES       SE
HI       VG
HI       NH
```

From this data PY will be the key and it's value will AB , similarly for all of the them.

But i want to handle a special case for a single key we have multiple values, like TD it has multiple values , in that i want to create an array
like 
`TD =[EF,IG,IH]` similarly  for all case where we will have this scenario

Could you please suggest how we can handle this case in Perl .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use an array to store all values for a key, below is demo program.

```
use Data::Dumper;    
my @key = qw/PY CH QQ TD TD TD TD TD ES HI HI/;
my @val = qw/AB BC CD EF IG IH RD GD SE VG NH/;
my $hash = {};
for (0..$#key) {
    push @{$hash->{$key[$_]}}, $val[$_];
}
print Dumper $hash;
```

Let's run it to see output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'HI' => [
                    'VG',
                    'NH'
                  ],
          'QQ' => [
                    'CD'
                  ],
          'TD' => [
                    'EF',
                    'IG',
                    'IH',
                    'RD',
                    'GD'
                  ],
          'PY' => [
                    'AB'
                  ],
          'ES' => [
                    'SE'
                  ],
          'CH' => [
                    'BC'
                  ]
        };
```

Answer (score 2):

Another Perl, using one-liner

```
perl -ne ' ($x,$y)=/(\S+)\s+(\S+)/; if( exists($kv{$x})) { @t=@{$kv{$x}}; push(@t,$y);$kv{$x}=[@t] } else { $kv{$x}=[$y]} ; END { foreach(keys %kv) { if(ref($kv{$_}) eq "ARRAY" ) { print "$_ => @{$kv{$_}}\n" } else { print "$_ ->$kv{$_}\n"  } }}' dev.txt
```

Output

```
HI => VG NH
QQ => CD
TD => EF IG IH RD GD
PY => AB
ES => SE
CH => BC
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the file line by line. For each value, push it into an array in a hashmap. The hashmap is keyed by your key values.

This line `push @{$hashref->{$key}}, $value;`

If the key exists in the map already, pushes the value onto an array associated with that key. If not, an array is initialised with the value, and the map is inistialised with that key.

```
my $hashref;
while(<>){
chomp;
my ($key, $value) = split;
push @{$hashref->{$key}}, $value;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `push @{$hashref->{$key}}, $value;`?

Comment: I'd recommend `while` over `foreach` here. That way, you only read the data a line at a time.